# ZF2: How Can I Use a Zend Filter Inside a Partial Loop?

Tags: zend-framework2, view-helpers

I have a ZF2 view script with some variables as follows:

```
$this->myModel = array($object1, $object 2, $object 3);
$this->myContext = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
$this->myFilter = new Zend\Filter\Word\SeparatorToCamelCase();
```

The view script calls the partial loop helper and passes the model:

```
$this->partialLoop->setObjectKey('model');
echo $this->partialLoop('my-template.phtml', $this->myModel)
```

In the partial script I am trying to access my context and filter as follows:

```
$context = $this->viewModel()->getCurrent()->myContext;
$filter = $this->viewModel()->getCurrent()->myFilter;
```

Accessing myConext this way works fine, but I get an error when trying to assign the filter to `$filter`.  Zend View seems to want to treat the object as a function and so it's `__invoke()` method is called.  Why is this?

I don't want to instantiate the filter in the partial script, or use the `StaticFilter`, since both would impact performance.

Answer (score 0):

Partials have own scope, so you can't use variables from parent template inside partial.

My workaround for same cases (not very beautiful, but working):

```
<? foreach ($this->myModel as $element) : ?>
     <?=$this->render('my-template.phtml', ['model' => $element] + $this->vars()->getArrayCopy())?>
<? endforeach ?>
```